# How far down were the crystal caves in Journey to the Center of the Earth?

Tags: journey-to-the-center-of-the-earth

How far down were the explorers when they found the crystalline caves in the 1960s movie *Journey to the Center of the Earth*?

Also, did any such caves exist at the time Jules Verne wrote the novel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the novel, just before they entered the crystal galleries, the barometer sat at just under 300 inches. A [quick calculation](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/epz/?n=wxcalc_pressurealtitude) reveals that, assuming the gallery wasn't under any kind of unusual air pressure, **the travelers were at a depth of approx 24 kilometers or just over 15 miles.**

> Breakfast over, my uncle drew from his pocket a small notebook, intended for scientific observations. He consulted his instruments, and recorded:
>   "Monday, July 1.
>   "Chronometer, 8.17 a.m.; **barometer, 297 in.**; thermometer, 6° (43° F.). Direction, E.S.E."

That being said, slightly later we get this passage

> **We had above us a league and a half of terrestrial crust**. The weight
>   of it seemed to be crushing down upon my shoulders. I felt weighed
>   down, and I exhausted myself with imaginary violent exertions to turn
>   round upon my granite couch.

A league is three miles, which makes a "*league and a half*" **something like 4.5 miles.** No explanation is given for the discrepancy.

---

Obviously no such depth has ever been reached [in reality](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2591742/Earths-deepest-cave-mapped-Amazing-diagram-charts-twist-turn-terrifying-7-200ft-deep-abyss.html) although [crystal caves](http://i800.photobucket.com/albums/yy287/stevep1031/San%20Diego%20Balboa%20Museums/_MG_0143.jpg) are a real phenomena and have been found worldwide.